# How to know when an AnchorEntity Action Sequence is finished?

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I have an `Action Sequence` that has a duration of 0.5 and then gets hidden when it hits 0 secs:

[image]

How can know when the action is done so that I can remove it from the `scene`? There isn't a way to do it with a [SCNNode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40935111/4833705), I'm hoping an `AnchorEntity` is different.

```
func session(_ session: ARSession, didAdd anchors: [ARAnchor]) {
    for anchor in anchors {
        if let anchorName = anchor.name, anchorName == "LaserBeam" {
            
            placeObject(named: anchorName, for: anchor)
        }
    }
}

func placeObject(named entityName: String, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
    do {
        
        let laserEntity = try ModelEntity.load(named: entityName)
        let anchorEntity = AnchorEntity(anchor: anchor)
        anchorEntity.addChild(laserEntity)

        arView.scene.addAnchor(anchorEntity)
        
    } catch let err as NSError {
        print(err.localizedDescription)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use either the [`subscribe(to:in:_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/scene/3254688-subscribe) or [`publisher(for:on: ) )`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/scene/3254685-publisher) if you prefer Combine on your `Scene` and pass [`AnimationEvents.PlaybackCompleted`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/realitykit/animationevents/playbackcompleted) as event to subscribe to.

Additionally, when using the `publisher` function you can use any Combine operator like [`filter(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/combine/publisher/filter(_:)) to subscribe to just the specific animation you want.